# format json not working in google-fluend

Tags: json, fluent, stackdriver

**Background**

Hi all,I am collecting logs from EC2 instance and sending it to StackDriver.All my logs are in JSON.

I am using the google-fluend agent and this is the configuration file for achieving this..

```
<source>
  type tail

  ***`format json`*** //////Issue:::When format json is used,my logs stop coming to stackdriver(Works well with format none).

  path /var/log/xyz/access.log
  read_from_head false
  tag springboot
</source>

<match springboot>
 type google_cloud
  # Set the chunk limit conservatively to avoid exceeding the limit
  # of 10MB per write request.
 buffer_chunk_limit 2M
 flush_interval 5s
  # Never wait longer than 5 minutes between retries.
 max_retry_wait 300
  # Disable the limit on the number of retries (retry forever).
 disable_retry_limit
  # Use multiple threads for processing.
 num_threads 8
</match>
```

**Issue**:

**format json** is not working,when i use it, logs stop coming to input file(/var/log/xyz/access.log) as well as to stackdriver.

Any thoughts how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a product manager with Google Stackdriver.  Two suggestions from the eng team here:

1. You can try sending the JSON to the forwarding port 24224 instead of the file.
2. If the JSON is more than a single line, it's possible that the parser is getting confused.